# question about query results in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

i'm working on MIMIC data set , i'm try to return patients id ,measurement id (itemid) and value of measurement. in this query , it returns all measurement related to 618 itemid only. How can i make him return all results related to both itemid. or return results related to 618 with percentage 60% of results and 40% for 676. i wish i could explain my question

```
select  subject_id  , itemid, value from chartevents
where itemid in (618 ,676)
```

all help will appreciated

Comment: you have in clause itemid in (618 ,676) so it should return results for both itemid?

Comment: results returns only for 618 for example

Comment: are there any method to specify percentage for every result?

Comment: You query will certainly return both.  Perhaps you just stop looking at them before you get down to the 676 ones.

Comment: ok, if i want him to return only patients have the both measurement

Comment: We can help more if you provide us with sample data and expected result. In this example, it's unclear how the percentage is calculated.

Comment: the database i query in contain several measurements for patients(note: not all patients have all measurements). in my question i try to return patients that only have values for both measurement  i am try this query                       
                                                                                                                     
............................................................................................................................select subject_id  , itemid, value from chartevents
where itemid in (618 ,676)

Comment: Again, if you can edit your Question to show some sample data (it can be completely fictitious) and the expected result, we can help more. Often you will find that asking a good question on this site requires a great deal of effort. Many times I have figured out the solution while I prepare a Question. In your case, I suspect some sort of subquery is necessary to aggregate the data you want.